# Does fetch and render + submit to index interrupt Google's crawl period?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

If you resubmit your site to the index in Webmaster Tools, will pending crawls get cancelled? I ask because a client's site has been up for 72 hours now and has not been crawled. I submitted to index once 72 hours ago, and once 24 hours ago because the page changed a bit.

Curious if resubmitting "interrupted" the crawl process or dropped me in the queue to get processed.

Comment: No. Google is not in a hurry. Relax. It will all work out. The best thing to do is create a link to the site. Fetch as Google and the regular crawl are two different things. One cannot force the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way through any Google tools to hurry or delay the crawl of a site. When you use tools such as Fetch and Render + submit it won't affect any queued crawling of the page in question, all it will do is add further details to the queue and submit the detected links to the queue as additional pages to crawl. Google can take anywhere from a few hours to two weeks to crawl a new site that it has just been informed about using any of its site submission tools. The only thing that you can do it give it time for the index to be updated in its own time.

Comment: Search console offers a way to change the crawl rate for your site: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en

Comment: This is only for adjusting the recurring regular crawling of the site not for speeding up an already pending crawl of a site. In addition the setting you are talking about is meant for throttling Googlebot from indexing your site too frequently, but it can't be used to force Google to crawl a site more frequently than the Google algorithms deem necessary.